# Why are the ticks of my axis displaced to the left?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a timeline in a `tikzpicture`. However, the ticks of my timeline are displaced to the left. Can someone please help me fix this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2ex]

%draw horizontal line   
\draw (1,0) -- (6,0);

%draw vertical line
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
   \draw (\x cm, 3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

%draw nodes
\draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 1 $} node[above=14pt] {RD};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 2 $} node[above=3pt] {Defendant enters market};
\draw (3,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 3 $} node[above=14pt] {Lawsuit};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 4 $} node[above=3pt] {PI Decision};
\draw (5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 5 $} node[above=14pt] {Final Decision};
\draw (6,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 6 $} node[above=3pt] {Final Pay-offs};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Replace `\draw (\x cm, 3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);` by `\draw (\x, 3pt) -- (\x,-3pt);`.

Comment: As @Jubobs hints, you force *x* values without a unit to be `x=2cm` but use `cm` in the `\foreach` loop, this is always evaluated to be `\x cm` regardless of the `x=` setting.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of unit vector changes you might use scales which without `transform shape` option don't affect the nodes. You can also shorten the code while you are at it...

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2]
\def\mylist{{"RD","Defendant enters market","Lawsuit",
             "PI Decision","Final Decision","Final Pay-offs"}}

\draw (1,0) -- (6,0);

\foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,6}{
   \draw (\x cm, 3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt)   node[below=3pt] at (\x,0) {$\x$}
   \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{Mod(\x,2)==0?"3pt":"14pt"}}
   node [above=\pgfmathresult] {\pgfmathparse{\mylist[\xi]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shorten - and make it illegible...

Comment: @TomasLycken There are only two nodes and one draw there, I mean come on :)

Answer (score 4):

You must be consistent with using `cm` units or no units.  Either specify each node as `(1 cm,0)`, etc. (which results in overlapping labels), or (as Jubobs suggests) remove the `cm` units in the foreach loop.  This yields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2ex]

%draw horizontal line   
\draw (1,0) -- (6,0);

%draw vertical line
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
   \draw (\x, 3pt) -- (\x,-3pt);

%draw nodes
\draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 1 $} node[above=14pt] {RD};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 2 $} node[above=3pt] {Defendant enters market};
\draw (3,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 3 $} node[above=14pt] {Lawsuit};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 4 $} node[above=3pt] {PI Decision};
\draw (5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 5 $} node[above=14pt] {Final Decision};
\draw (6,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 6 $} node[above=3pt] {Final Pay-offs};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in which everything lines up properly.  The problem is that, since you specified `x=2cm` in the environment options, "bare" coordinates (without units) are multiples of `x` (2cm), whereas if you specify units, you get what you ask for.  (This mismatch doesn't show up by default, since initially the x-vector is 1cm.)

Note that there are two different coordinate systems in TikZ specified by `(x,y)` pairs.  The **xyz** system is used when there are no dimensions (units of length), as in `(2,3)`.  As you've seen, these are factors which multiply the `x` and `y` vectors, whose values can be specified.  The **canvas** system is used when dimensions are supplied, as in `(2 cm, 7 pt)`.  When you mix systems (as you did), these are the rules (from the TikZ manual):

> Note: It is possible to use coordinates like `(1,2cm)`, which are
>   neither **canvas** coordinates nor **xyz** coordinates. The rule is the
>   following: If a coordinate is of the implicit form `(⟨x⟩,⟨y⟩)`, then `⟨x⟩` and `⟨y⟩` are checked, independently, whether they have a
>   dimension or whether they are dimensionless. If both have a dimension,
>   the **canvas** coordinate system is used. If both lack a dimension, the
>   **xyz** coordinate system is used. If `⟨x⟩` has a dimension and `⟨y⟩` has
>   not, then the sum of two coordinate `(⟨x⟩,0pt)` and `(0,⟨y⟩)` is used. If
>    `⟨y⟩` has a dimension and `⟨x⟩` has not, then the sum of two coordinate
>   `(⟨x⟩,0)` and `(0pt,⟨y⟩)` is used.
>
> Note furthermore: An expression like
>   `(2+3cm,0)` does not mean the same as `(2cm+3cm,0)`. Instead, if `⟨x⟩` or
>   `⟨y⟩` internally uses a mixture of dimensions and dimensionless values,
>   then all dimensionless values are "upgraded" to dimensions by
>   interpreting them as `pt`. So, `2+3cm` is the same dimension as `2pt+3cm`.